# Dev C++ ld returned 1 exit status (C language)

Tags: c, return, dev-c++

I started a C programming course. I am on lesson 2 and I am pretty new. I have done everything
in course true but my program always gives these errors:

```
"C:\Users\Win10\Desktop\C\collect2.exe  [Error] ld returned 1 exit status"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe   cannot open output file C:\Users\Win10\Desktop\C\main.exe: Permission denied".
```

I am using Dev C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main() {
    getch(); //gereksiz yazıları siler
    printf("Hello Programmer...\n");
    int x = 12;
    float e = 12.3;
    char h = 'e';
    printf("%c", h);
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you are still having the main.exe running from the previous exercise? If you have main.exe running then close it, and try to compile again.

Comment: It isn't working and I compiled it again but nothing changed.

Comment: As @Alex said, your executable yourprogram.exe is in use. Terminate the program with ctrl+c on the console and retry compiling.

Comment: There is no exe application running on shortcuts place on Windows. I looked in Task Manager but I didn't found anything like my program name (main.c or main.exe). If I restart my pc will it be fixed?

Comment: Oh I found main.exe's are running in background. I used Process Lasso. Maybe if I terminate them it will be fixed.

Comment: Yes when I termiante them my code started working fine. Thank you so much.